# Python get the total execution time of a function

Tags: python, decorator, profiler

Suppose that I have a function:

```py
def func(x):
    time.sleep(x)
    return x
```

It will be called in every place when needed, for example, `func_a in class A`, `func_b in class B`... And all the modules start from a main function, `main()`.

Now I want to statistic the amount of the called freqs and time of `func`. It's similar to `profiler`, but I only want to get the statistics of `func`; I do not care about other methods.

A Decorator can only get the time once, which is not sufficient for the total time. Another problem is that `func` overrides a function in another package. It may be called by functions in the package, and it is not easy to add a decorator to every call method.

```py
def time(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
         import time
         st = time.time()
         result = func(*args, **kwargs)
         end = time.time()
         print(f"execution time: {end - st}")
         return result
     return wrapper()
@time
def func(x):
    ...
```

Is there any simple method that I can use to get the total execution of `func` with the minimum code?

Comment: What you have seems like a solid idea to me. You can also test functions in other packages by wrapping them directly (eg, `timed_external_method = time(external_method)` because that's what decorators do anyway.

Comment: you can use class based decorator and store data there

Comment: Thanks, that's the most direct way. However, with the decorator, I have to maintain a global variable to count the total time and then pass it to the decorator. Getting the execution time with `return in wrapper` will make me change the original call to exclude the return time. Both are tedious. A lot of code should be changed. Maybe a formatted log analysed after execution is a good choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to have the total execution time printed next to the execution time of the current call, you can store the total execution time as a local variable in the decorator and add to it the execution time of each call:

```
import time

def timer(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        nonlocal total
        start = time.time()
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        duration = time.time() - start
        total += duration
        print(f"Execution time: {duration}   Total: {total}")
        return result

    total = 0
    return wrapper
```

Demo: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVBBTsMwELzvK6ye4lCqAhdUKRIXfsAHrNSBCNe2Nms1CPXtqXdrTBA@WOvZ2dnxxC/6CP7pOeKyjKcYkBSNJwtwtINU2AzJ9/oAKh8Gz2hizHBr8H3aqrb9PHNVGHx88C70xikKZFyFJzJZvRPVHV@Nrj20U3Lc5GX/pCvtmNDQGPxfFXV/06402avuusqvnYijp2bYvM62T6LEEgf1/cO8ZNIbj2dMZC6btUtK6ItZgN9VndrDilAiAoAXiVDClJ/NJSZxPzlrY4bWo3MeKiaZ/6D1@vmo9bJcAQ)

Or if you want to be able to access the total execution time separately, you can expose it as an additional attribute of the wrapper function object:

```
import time

def timer(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start = time.time()
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        duration = time.time() - start
        wrapper.total_time += duration
        print(f"Execution time: {duration}")
        return result

    wrapper.total_time = 0
    return wrapper
```

so that:

```
@timer
def func(x):
    time.sleep(x)
    return x

print(func(1))
print(func(2))
print(f'Total: {func.total_time}')
```

outputs:

```
Execution time: 1.00111985206604
1
Execution time: 2.0005435943603516
2
Total: 3.0016634464263916
```

Demo: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZDPbsIwDMbvfoqIC035o7FdEFIlLrwBdxRBulUraeQ6ogjx7CUOWcg0zYcosX/@8tn2Sl@d@VhbHMfmbDskQc1ZA5x0HW5Y1M4c5QaED05eUFnr06XCz34uyvL7wrdIcPSkvEwV2pd8FDLVUPeu5SKr/tFI2MmhoqYzv1XE4qmdsOhlSR2p9sCQmFWpOWEWG0NFPdkN@uiCLKMbcfsh75PcITk00SjAP99U4g0yOhIAsA1LC@sLIw5xMWGMvtXa@lTeOvimaJD5lZT58/31nO75e@@aC5mX@1SO4wM)

Comment: I write a class decorator with `self.cum_time` to count the total execution time. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, a class-based decorator would be the most versatile, but if all you want is to store additional information such as total execution time, a new class may be somewhat of an overkill.

Comment: I agree with you. As I want to customize when to clear the `total_time` to restart the record according to the top caller in the call stack, the class-based decorator is flexible to extend.